# libwebsockets - compresssion (deflate)

Tags: libwebsockets

I'm trying to figure out how to enable deflate compression **on the client** with libwebsockets, for both send and receive.

Documentation seems sparse, I understand that I'd need to:

- Configure lws with `LWS_WITH_HTTP_STREAM_COMPRESSION`
- Use `lws_http_compression_apply` ???

I'm not clear on the second part - do I need to call this function twice, to enable compression support for both outgoing and incoming data? Is compression then optionally supported - and depends on what the server also supports - or mandatory (and will fail if the server doesn't support it)?

Any pointers would be appreciated.